# Insert Hyperlink button not visible in Word CustomUI

Tags: ms-word, ribbonx

I have created the following XML for our Word CustomUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab idMso="TabHome">
        <group idMso="GroupFont" visible="false" />
        <group idMso="GroupParagraph" visible="false" />
        <group idMso="GroupInsertTables" insertBeforeMso="GroupStyles" />
        <group id="CustGrp1" label="Next" insertBeforeMso="GroupStyles">
            <toggleButton idMso="AlignLeft" showLabel="false" />
            <toggleButton idMso="AlignCenter" showLabel="false" />
            <toggleButton idMso="AlignRight" showLabel="false" />

            <button idMso="IndentDecreaseWord" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="IndentIncreaseWord" showLabel="false" />
            <gallery idMso="MultilevelListGallery" showLabel="false" /> 

            <gallery idMso="FontColorPicker" showLabel="false" />
            <gallery idMso="ShadingColorPicker" showLabel="false" />
            <toggleButton idMso="Superscript" showLabel="false" />

            <button idMso="SpellingAndGrammar" showLabel="false" />
            <splitButton idMso="TableBordersMenu" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="SymbolsDialog" showLabel="false" />
            <button idMso="HyperlinkInsert" showLabel="true" />

            <gallery idMso="AutoTextGallery" showLabel="true" />
            <button idMso="BookmarkInsert" showLabel="true" />
            <button id="ReferenceInsert" label="Referentie" imageMso="CrossReferenceInsert" onAction="modCode.ButtonOnAction" />

            <button idMso="ReviewNewComment" showLabel="false" />
            <toggleButton idMso="ParagraphMarks" showLabel="false" />
          </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

The HyperlinkInsert button is not visible. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

[screenshot CustomUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6BNP.png)

Comment: It works for me... Which version of Word running in which OS?

Comment: We use Word 365 Pro Plus Version 1810  (build 11001.20074 Klik-en-Klaar) Dutch language pack. OS = Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

We have this issue with the latest Word in 2023.  I think its because the hyperlink button is now a custom dropdown.  While it is called a button by the ribbon config, its not really one.  You can't add it to a custom ribbon tab link in Word 2016 and before.

We worked around this by reimplementing the call to create the link.

It takes some code but you can reuse parts of Word such as the ribbon portion which uses the standard Word image:

```
<button id="linkId" label="Hyperlink" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" onAction="yourMethod"/>
```

and we use the standard Word hyperlink UI which can be called within yourMethod() as

```
// Show the standard Word hyperlink dialog, when the user presses Ok, the link is created
var dialog = currentRange.Application.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogInsertHyperlink];
object oTimeout = Type.Missing;
dialog.Show(ref oTimeout);
```

The return result from the .Show() is supposed to indicate if the user pressed Ok or Cancel, but in practice, it always returns -1 and if you care about the result, you need to see if Word created a link at the selection.